# Test suites always failing - Randomly

Tags: node.js, express, testing, jestjs, supertest

I have being studing Jest and i currently doing a lot of integrations tests on my api, using sqlite for the db test.

But something strange is that sometimes a test go well and then fail again. I don't know if the reason for that is related to some truncate that i doing on the db after run a test suite.

Here's the repo with the tests: https://github.com/LauraBeatris/gympoint-api

If someone run `yarn test` probably will have the user test suite failed and also the registrations test suite failed.

I will appreciate a help!

Comment: Is there any error output as to why the test failed?

Comment: It is always related to 404 status but sometimes all the tests suites run and have success. I think that in some point i'm truncating the db and erasing some data.

Comment: Do you wait or confirm that what you've inserted into the DB is there before running your test?